# Print in php side

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a list item which is Executive Room, when i click that list, I call the myFunction('tabExe') method with a parameter "tabExe", In my console, it prints the value "tabExe", does it populate the variable successfully ? and I have a textarea below the list item, how to print the value in the textarea using php? please help... tnx

//HTML

```
<li>
    <a name="tabExe" onClick="myFunction('tabExe');" id="tabExe" href="#Exec">
      Executive Room</a>
</li>
<textarea id="source1" name="source1" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
```

//JavaScript

```
function myFunction(str){

    var val = str;
    alert(val);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ROOMS.php',
    data: {
        source1 : val,
        },
    success: function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The above code as far as I can tell will call `ROOMS.PHP` with the source1 paramter.  Is this what you want?

Comment: You'll get *tabExe* in your ROOMS.php page as **$_POST['source1']**. What do you need to print in Text area?

Comment: I want to print the value of source1 to the text area . Pls help, KUDOS in advance!

Comment: thanks a lot dude! i can already print the value in the text area, but i get this error " Notice: Undefined index: source1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\backEnd\ROOMS.php on line 3" whenever i use this code in my php side <?php $src1= $_POST['source1']; echo $src1; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the data inside textarea, rewrite your function to be:

```
function myFunction(str){

  var val = str;
  alert(val);
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ROOMS.php',
  data: {
      source1 : val,
      },
  success: function( data ) {
      $('#source1').val(data);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! it did print in the text area, but can you help me in printing the value of source1 in my php side.. i tried using this code "<?php 

$src1= $_POST['source1'];  

echo $src1; 

?>"  but it says " Notice: Undefined index: source1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\backEnd\ROOMS.php on line 3"

Comment: check if it is set or not, `isset($_POST['source1'])` then if it's not then track it back :)... if my previous answer helped you, please mark it as best answer :)